# Elementary question about construction of uniform measure on $\mathcal{B} _{(0,1]}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading Amir Dembo's lecture notes (http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf) about the construction of the uniform probability measure on $(0,1]$.

On Page 13, the lecture notes define $$\mathcal{A} = \{(a_1,b_1] \cup \ldots \cup (a_r,b_r]: 0\leq a_1 < b_1 < \ldots <a_r<b_r \leq 1, r<\infty \}.$$ This is an algebra and the notes go on to use Caratheodory's extension theorem to construct a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal A) = \mathcal{B} _{(0,1]}$.

This seems like a roundabout construction to my newbie eyes: constructing it on an algebra first and then extending it to the sigma-algebra generated by that algebra. Why can't one explicitly construct a uniform probability measure on $\mathcal{B} _{(0,1]}$ by a process like:

1) Every element in $\mathcal{B} _{(0,1]}$ can be written as $\cup_i (a_i,b_i]$, where the $i$s may take values in an uncountable set.

2) Write down the set function $U_0 \left( \cup_{k=1}^{r} (a_k,b_k] \right) = \sum _{k=1}^r (b_k-a_k)$

3) Prove that $U_0$ is countably additive

?

Comment: What you say under 1) is not true. As a newbie you might not know yet, but $\mathcal B_{(0,1]}$ contains lots of sets that cannot be written as a union of half-open (left) half-closed (right) intervals. For instance sets like $\{x\}$ where $x\in(0,1]$, or a set like $(0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks, I see. So the general principle is, when there is no way to explicitly write the elements of a sigma algebra, then one has to resort to such indirect constructions?

Comment: You could say so, yes. Moreover that works fine. The indirectness is not really bothering.